# Accessing resources from the main program in a JUnit test with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, junit, classpath

I've ran into a problem that people seem to have often. I need to access some resources (namely, migrations) that are in my main class resources folder.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875635/cant-access-files-from-src-main-resources-via-a-test-case) post talks about, however the proposed solution does not work. The resources in `src/main/resources` are not available to my JUnit test.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977959/junit-test-should-use-main-resources) post has a solution referencing Maven, which doesn't do me much good because I am in Gradle land.

For reference the follow code does *not* work

```
public class ConnectorTests {

  @Before
  public void initialize() throws SQLException {
    Reader vendorSql = new InputStreamReader(
        this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
            "/migrations/V0__create_vendor_table.sql"));
```

It gives an expected null pointer exception because the file is not found.

I can confirm this is the problem, because by copying the file in question into `src/test/resources/migrations` it works just fine. This is not ideal however because  that means I have an extra step when I change or add a migration.

Is there some classpath voodoo I need to do in Gradle to get this to work correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`google guava`](https://github.com/google/guava)

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '19.0'
```

And then call your resources folder in that way :

```
URL url = Resources.getResource("migrations/V0__create_vendor_table.sql");
String text = Resources.toString(url, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

That worked for me...

Comment: Wouldn't this still have the same problem? Namely JUnit looks in `src/test/resources` rather than `src/main/resources`?